# EntityFramework tries to CAST enum to number

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, enums, ef-code-first

I am using **EntityFramework 6.1.3** with **Oracle** and I have enum like below:

```
public enum Terms
{
    NotSpecified, I, II, III, IV
}
```

I have entity which uses this enum:

```
public class Report
{
    public short Year { get; set; }
    public Terms TermId { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to filter according to TermId generated query casts TermId to *Number(10, 0)*:

```
Terms termId = Terms.I;
IQueryable<Report> query = ....;
query = query.Where(m => m.Termid == termId);
```

Generated query tries to cast Term and it is very slow:

```
WHERE (( CAST( "Extent1"."TERM" AS NUMBER(10,0))) = :p_ling_0);
```

When I remove `CAST` it is lightning fast. I tried setting `HasColumnType`, changing type of Enum to short, byte and following scenarios without success:

```
.Where(m => (int)m.Termid == (int)termId); // Casting is still there
.Where(m => m.Termid.Equals(termId)); // Equals is not supported for Enums
.Where(m => ((int)termId).Equals((int)m.Termid)); // Casting is still there
```

How can I prevent EF generating query with `CAST`?

Comment: According to https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/186 this should be fixed since EF 6.1.2 
Anyway, you may rely on the fix proposed in the comments

Comment: @jbl, probably the comment you mentioned is deleted before I saw. May be it is fixed for MS Sql Server, bit it persists for Oracle

Comment: The comment I was referring to was one in the EF work item linked above

Comment: @jbl ok, i will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @jbl unfortunatelly it didn't help